# Pullback of global sections of twisted ideal sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $C_1, C_2$ be  integral curves on $X$. Let $n$ be such that the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_{C_1 \cup C_2}(n)$ is globally generated as an $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}$-module. 
Assume that $C_1 \cup C_2$ is connected.
Under what condition on $C_1$ and $C_2$ is the natural morphism $H^0(X,\mathcal{I}_{C_1 \cup C_2}(n)) \to H^0(C_1, \mathcal{I}_{C_1 \cup C_2} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}} \mathcal{O}_{C_1}(n))$ surjective? 
For example if $C_1, C_1 \cup C_2$ are both complete intersection curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (not in $X$) can this hold true?